# How to efficiently remove duplicated user defined data from vector?

Tags: c++, vector

Let's define a simple struct A.

```
struct A
{
   int x,y,z;
};
```

I want to remove some elements from vector by following rules.

```
if two compared segments' x is same, remove one which has larger y value.

[before remove]
x y z
1 2 3
1 3 4 
1 4 5

[after remove]
x y z
1 2 3
```

Another rules.

```
if two compared segment's x and y values are same, remove one which has smaller z value.
[before remove]
x y z
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5

[after remove]
1 2 5
```

I have used unique and erase function in STL to solve this problem.. like below

```
bool compare_x(const A & p1, const A & p2)
{
    if(p1.x == p2.x) // to erase larger one.
        return p1.y < p2.y
}


...
vector<A> list; // let's assume that this vector has some data.

list.erase(unique(list.begin(), list.end(), compare_x), list.end());
```

but some people said to me that unique function does not work well..

So I want to know about any technique or function that can be solve this kind of works.

Thanks.

Comment: You should show what you have tried, and what about it that's not working.

Comment: many people say many things, but if your code works as expected, maybe they are wrong. Why do you think there is something wrong with your method?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this implementation. I retracted my previous comment because the erase-remove idiom wouldn't work in this case. The erase-unique that you already have, works well. Why would std::unique not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove all duplicates, the range given to `std::unique` must have all duplicate elements adjacent to each other. The order in which the elements are sorted affects which of the duplicate are not removed. So, the correct solution is `std::sort`, `std::unique`, `erase`.

Secondly, `compare_x` is bogus. It lacks a return statement in case `p1.x != p2.x`. The behaviour is undefined. Besides, the predicate cannot tell the algorithm which of the equivalent element to erase; It tells the algorithm which elements are equivalent. Which element is erased depends on their position in the input range. The first equivalent element is kept.

The solution to the problem lies in using a different predicate for sort and unique. Unique needs a more relaxed criteria, while sorting needs to have the same criteria, except in equal cases it should sort so that the removal happens to correct elements.

> if two compared segments' x is same, remove one which has larger y value.

Unique predicate: Only by `x`.

Sorting predicate: By `x`, then `y`. `y` must be sorted in ascending order.

> if two compared segment's x and y values are same, remove one which has smaller z value.

Unique predicate: By `x` and `y`.

Sorting predicate: By `x` and `y`, then by `z`. `z` must be sorted in descending order.